# PowerBI Connection RDS Postgres SSH

Tags: postgresql, ssh, powerbi, amazon-rds

I would like to connect PowerBI to a PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS RDS secured by an SSH Tunnel.
I tried to create a connexion on my laptop with PowerBI installed through Putty and then create a Postgres connexion on PowerBI.
No problem to create the SSH connexion with Putty but PowerBI is not able to create the connexion with the database.

Is there a way to access this database with PowerBI ?

Comment: What error do you get?  This sounds primarily like a Putty issue.  Did you configure putty to tunnel?

Comment: You are right! I change few things on the Tunnel config and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Process I followed :

1. Configuration of the destination :
   [image]
2. Add the private key (I transformed it from RSA to .ppk with Puttygen)

[image]

3. Configure connexion

[image]

4. Configure Connexion >> Data

[image]

5. Configure Tunnel

[image]

6. Clik on "open", then a terminal will open :

[image]

7. Open PowerBi desktop, add a postgreSQL data source, Name= localhost and database = postgres